# -Confirm:$false set as global setting

Tags: powershell

I have a few powershell scripts which trigger from a C# codepart.

They run non-interactive and there is no way to confirm any command.

In Powershell, we can set the `ErrorActionPreference` global with `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`

Is there a same way to set on each command the confirm parameter to $false if it exists ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$ConfirmPreference = "None"
```

Read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/15/confirmpreference.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/15/confirmpreference.aspx)

You can set the global behavior with

```
$ConfirmPreference = "None" / "Low" / "High"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the command supports Confirm and set it using splatting:

```
$param = @{}
if((Get-Command Enable-PSRemoting).Parameters.Confirm) {$param.Confirm=$false}

Enable-PSRemoting @param
```

In PowerShell 3.0 you can use the $PSDefaultParameterValues variable:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues["*:Confirm"]=$false
```

Comment: But with your way, I have to make this code on each command, but I want it as global setting, as I said.

Comment: For 3.0 isn't just: `$PSDefaultParameterValues["confirm"]=$false` ? or `$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{"*:confirm"=$false}`

Comment: @Solaflex I thought you wanted " to set on each command", my bad.

Comment: @ShayLevy You are rigth, there is an error in the help at the sintax: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847819.aspx